# MCAS - Enable service workers

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365, microsoft365-defender

My app uses service workers to handle file downloads using an approach similar to streamsaver.js. When a user visits the app using MCAS we get the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Service worker registration is disabled by MDA
    at ServiceWorkerContainer.register (js-wrapper.js:2:29415)
    at ServiceWorkerContainer.register (js-wrapper.js:2:92717)
    at <anonymous>:15:215
```

js-wrapper has a method `y.get` that returns the MCAS config including `disableServiceWorker: true`. I can't find anything useful in the docs or from searches. Does the MCAS proxy support web workers and if so, where is the configuration for it?